# How can I retrieve my post request using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, django

I have two projects, the first one is `Node.JS`.

```
        jsonobj = JSON.stringify(generateMockData)
        xhrToSoftware.send(jsonobj);
        xhrToAPI.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/", true);
        xhrToAPI.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhrToAPI.send(jsonobj);
```

It's sending data to the second project `Django Python`. I can receive the data using my views.py.

```
post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8")) 
value = post_data.get('data')
print(value)
```

But I want to directly get the data from `Node.JS` to my `Django Templates (javascript or jquery)` is that possible?

for example:

```
<script>
 //get the data that posted by the node.js
</script>
```

UPDATE:

I tried using the answers below like this one:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

but I'm having an error it says that:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!-- 
 
<d"... is not valid JSON
```

I think that's because I'm returning an html file in my views.py:

```
def data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))  # for simulation
        value = post_data.get('data')
    return render(request, 'waterplant/iot/data.html')
```

so, I change it to jsonresponse like this:

```
def data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))  # for simulation
        value = post_data.get('data')
        return JsonResponse({"msg": value}, status=200)
```

After that I'm having an error `ValueError: The view views.data didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` I think that's because the value is empty yet. How can I prevent that? If I send a data using my `Node.JS` I want to return it as `return JsonResponse({"msg": value}, status=200)` Or you have any idea that I can access the data directly in my Django Python templates `<script> here </script>`

Comment: Are you trying get data from db using nodejs or trying to make a request from UI to nodejs server?
Because here both the UI and server are using JavaScript.. :|

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my question hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If a get request is to be made from your webpage use `fetch()`

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/path')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I tried this one but I'm having error it says VM60366:1 
        
       Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!-- 
 
<d"... is not valid JSON

Comment: there is a lot of assumption from my side since we dont have the code snippet and im not clear of the language u have provided above.

 return JsonResponse({"msg": value}, status=200) is still not json is it? should the code be more like this JsonResponse({"msg": value, 'status':200});

Answer (score 1):

- ***Basic js fetch()***

If you use method "GET":

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/path')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

If you use method "POST":

```
fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/path`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
            body: data
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error on fetch() call:\n', error));
```

- *Hope it could be useful!*

Comment: I tried the GET one but I'm having error it says VM60366:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!-- <d"... is not valid JSON

Comment: It may be that the data you receive is not a json, in (.then(response => response.json()) we expect to receive a json, if instead you receive a different type of data, it must be specified, for example if you know you receive a string, it will be (.then(response => response.text())

More info:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-fetch-api-tutorial-with-js-fetch-post-and-header-examples/